# What could be the reason behind "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"?

Tags: networking, portforwarding

I am using (airtel xstream fiber) connection and trying to do port forwarding. I forwarded port `3000` of wan and direct it to my system ip address `192.168.1.2` on port `3001`.

Node server is running on my system on port 3001. And I can access my hello world website locally using `192.168.1.2:3001`. But when I am trying to access using public ip, it show this error code "`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`".

Also, I found my router port `3001` is open using online port checking tool/website.

So, Can anyone please tell what could be reason behind this ? Is this the problem with windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No there is no need for static IP to be access server remotely. As of now, What I see is airtel allocates new ip every 24 hr or when router got disconnected. To access your server remotely you can do two things. First one is more secured.

1. Change Primary IP adress of your airtel router and use Portforwarding so that its port 80 will be free for you.
2. Enable DMZ and point it to your local server IP. [192.168.X.X]. In this case all of your ports of the device are exposed to internet. If you want to be secure. Make sure add another router between server and airtel router and enable port forwarding.

But in this case there is a catch, When you try to access your local website using public ip (which you can see on google search) it will redirect you to airtel router panel. But when you try to access it using other device (not server otherwise server will get disconnected) connected to internet using other network(other that your current airtel router like JIO sim, Airtel Sim, etc), It will work excellently.

To get rid of dynamic ip use no-ip services. Its website will help you more. Basically, It is dynamic dns server where you will get free domain. That will get update regularly while its service running on your system. To use other dns provider service like godaddy you must need an static ip.

Comment: One can also, manipulate disabled router settings easily. Ask me how to do it.

Comment: I have a Pi connected to my router. And I want to make that accessible from internet via noip host. It would be great if you could give steps for a fresh router installation.

Comment: which internet provider are you using ? BTW, If you want we can make a google meet ?

Comment: I'm using Airtel Xstream Fiber... Sure, we can use google meet.

Comment: https://meet.google.com/znv-jjxw-wae Here is the link to google meet.  I will be active after 2PM (IST) anytime. So please comment here the time u r comfortable with. BTW, I will be online by 7PM.

Comment: Sure.. I'm online now as well. And I'll join the given link around 2 PM today. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will be also there by 2pm.

Comment: I tried all steps but its not working for me, port 80 not getting accessible from outside world

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check what ports are open by your ISP. If your ISP is giving you a local ip at the router. Basically, creating a ppp connection. It may be using a cg nat. In that case you need to buy a static ip, without that none of the traffic will be Directed to your router. Let me know if you find something, I'm currently looking to get xstream airtel as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the asnwer that i found to make it work. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh okay, got it. Just wanted to confirm one thing, that the your public ip matches the ip that you get at the router? So, if there is a cg nat at isp, both ip's will be different. But as you are using the setup as given in below answer, it seems that there is no cg nat and you're getting public ip on your router directly. In any case, I'll get the xstream connection and try it on my own. Thanks.